# How do I make the most minimal vanilla theme possible with nothing but raw content?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have two themes. One is the full blown already completed theme. With the second theme I only want to show the contents or custom field contents of the post. Absolutely nothing else.

I thought this would be easy but there are 755 files in the theme that I copied. I just want a theme with one or two pages.

How do I make a theme with nothing but content? I'm talking no html, no css, no markup, just raw data.

URL's would work like this

```
www.mysite.com/myblog/ ---> list of only posts content
www.mysite.com/myblog/?postId=100 ---> only content of post id 100
```

Comment: Try my [mini theme](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most minimal theme possible has two files: `style.css` and `index.php`.

**`style.css`**

```
/* Theme Name: Bare-bones theme*/
```

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you could make it more "vanilla" than that. Keep in mind that any HTML markup within the post's content will still be returned.

See [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) for more information, or the [WP REST API plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/) for an alternative approach to returning data without additional markup.

Comment: I share the same idea of using WP REST API (which will be included in the core soon instead of struggling with strange themes to output content in certain ways.

WP REST API + AngularJS, EmberJS, or ReactJS are a nicer approach in developing websites and mobile apps integrating WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the REST API, @shawncampbell. (The funny thing is, I didn't consider the API even though I'm using it for almost this exact purpose on a work project.)